# Android Studio: Unable to change background color and text color based on boolean

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I am building a todo application. My goal is for the item's background color to change to red and the font to white, if urgent = true (boolean).

I am able to do this, but unfortunately once it changes the true todo, it will also change the todo before, even if it equals false.

I know the issue is in the getView method (see below). I have tried moving the textView = newView.findViewById(R.id.textView), above the if old == null statement, but that seems to crash the app. I have also moved the if urgent == true statement into the other if statement, and that won't work either.

Any ideas what may be causing the issue?

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View old, ViewGroup parent) {

            View newView = old;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            if(old == null) {
                newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_items, parent, false);
            }

            textView = newView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(getItem(position).toString());

            if(urgent == true) {
                newView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

            return newView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the adapter's full code?

Comment: Don't you need an `else` in there to reset the color when urgent is false? `if(urgent[position]) { set red } else { set black }`. Otherwise an urgent view that is recycled will stay red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array of booleans to keep track of the state for each item in the listview

Try changing

```
if(urgent == true) {
   newView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

To

```
if(urgent[position]) {
    newView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
} else {
    //Put here the default colors
    newView.setBackgroundColor(  );
    textView.setTextColor(  );
}
```

this should fix the issue, also you don't need to do `if(boolean == true)` `if(boolean)` is enough

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have an array (or list) of `urgent` variables, for each position in the list. When item in the list is updated by scroll of by other reason, all views are updated according to the one `urgent` var.